# PWM Arduino output signal

Tags: arduino, pwm

I used this code to generate a 32kHz 50% duty cycle PWM output:

```
int pwmpin = 3;
void setup()
  TCCR2B = TCCR2B & B11111000 | B00000001;
  pinMode(pwmpin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int pwmvalue = 511;
  pwmvalue = map(pwmvalue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  analogWrite(pwmpin, pwmvalue);
}
```

The output signal looks like this (shows 2 signals), why? the oscilloscope is properly calibrated.

[image]

Comment: Are you concerned that the signals overlap, or that they have spikes at the transitions?

Comment: Both actually, but most importantly why do they overlap?

Comment: There's a { missing after void setup(). Is this the actual code you used?

Comment: No, I deleted that by mistake while posting the question

Comment: Your ground connection between MCU and scope is broken?

Comment: Amplitude at left-side of oscillograph is *higher* than amplitude at right-side of oscillograph. Perhaps the "overlap" is caused by a super-imposed 50 Hz (or 60 Hz) signal. One possible cause is missing or broken ground connection as @Justme has suggested. The apparent overlap is caused by triggered sweeps not repeating exactly.

Comment: How can I figure which ground connection is broken? and what other reasons can cause this superimposed signal to interfere?

Comment: Turn the timebase down so that you're seeing at least one full cycle of your local power line frequency (so, around 2ms per division).  If you see a sine wave impressed on your signal, you've got a grounding problem.  It'll be pretty obvious, and it's a dead easy test.  *Any* time you see your scope trace looking weird you should zoom in and out and look at different time scales.

Comment: Actually, you should just make a habit of zooming in and out when you look at stuff with a scope -- in case there's weirdness there that you're not seeing.

Comment: The spikes could be ground bounce, depending on where you are referencing ground from.  Arduinos can have some pretty big spikes.  See: https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/blogs/12-fundamentals/post/1207-seven-habits-of-successful-2-layer-board-designers

Comment: Remember that your oscilloscope is showing more than just one pass at a time. It overlays several waveforms from separate trigger events unless you use single-shot trigger mode.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can connect the Arduino to power supply so the ground of the Arduino will not be broken with the scope

Comment: Not really.  What is needed is to connect the scope's probe ground to the circuit being examined.  Some types of power supplies may make that unsafe to even do, though hopefully the asker does not have one.  Relying on the mains ground through both a power supply and the scope's mains supply is a poor choice of ground reference to take a high frequency measurement as that is a very long path; but the probe grounding does need to not be *inconsistent* with a mutual ground through the mains.